# How to correctly skip setValue if value is null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I want to read out values from a specific row in one sheet, and insert them into another sheet underneath each other. The problem is that if a cell is empty, I obviously do not want to insert an empty value underneath the last value in the new sheet. What I did do is the following loop:

```
var lastCol = ppt2019.getLastColumn();
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(
    'Enter row to read out values from'
).getResponseText();     
var row2 = 4;

for (var i = 0; i <= lastCol - 3; i++) {
    var plakatMenge = ppt2019.getRange(row, 3 + i).getValues();
    if (plakatMenge === "") {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        newSheet.getRange(row2, 3).setValue(plakatMenge);
        row2++;
    }
}
```

It reads out the values and puts it into the correct column and starting row, but instead of just skipping to `setValues` in that cell if the read out value is empty, it still puts in an empty value. It should look like this:

```
Values
10
10
20
30
10
```

but looks like this, instead:

```
Values

10



10

20



30
10
```

For comparison, here is the complete script (I am not a programmer, so do not please don't judge the lack of form)

```
function tourzettelV4() {      
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ppt2019 = app.getSheetByName("PlakatTool2019");      
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(
    'Gib die Zeile mit dem Datum für die Tour ein'
  ).getResponseText();

  var dateTour = ppt2019.getRange(row, 1).getValue();

  var makeNewSheet = app.getSheetByName("Tour " + dateTour);
  if (makeNewSheet != null) {
    app.deleteSheet(makeNewSheet);
  }
  makeNewSheet = app.insertSheet();
  makeNewSheet.setName("TourzettelV2");

  var newSheet = app.getSheetByName("TourzettelV2")
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(dateTour);
  newSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("Gebiet:");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 1).setValue("Was");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 2).setValue("Format");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 3).setValue("Menge");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 4).setValue("Info");  

  var lastCol = ppt2019.getLastColumn();

  var checkCol = 3;
  var row2 = 4;

  for (var i = 0; i <= lastCol - 3; i++) {
    var plakatMenge = ppt2019.getRange(row, 3 + i).getValues();
    if (plakatMenge === ""){
      continue;
    }
    else {
      newSheet.getRange(row2, 3).setValue(plakatMenge);
      row2++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: More than likely, `plakatMenge` is a value other than "". Maybe try to console.log that value and see if it is possibly `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: You almost have it.   Youre checking for empty string, expand it to say:  `|| ... === null` ?

Comment: Change ```if(plakatMenge === ""){``` line to ```if(!plakatMenge){```

Comment: Problem was the === had to be ==. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

```
if(plakatMenge === ""){
            continue;
      }
```

This block is not executing ,because you are doing strict type checking. 
give a try by using == instead of ===. I hope it'll work.

Comment: That worked! Oh my god, I can't believe it was something so "easy" to fix. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter for blanks here is how I would do it:

```
plakatMenge = plakatMenge.filter( function(_platkaMenge) {
return _platkaMenge[0] !== undefined
})
```

Comment: not true, I use them in my google apps Script all the time

Comment: raphael @ruben meant arrow functions, not array functions

Comment: hahah yeah he is right there let me fix that lol, I'm so used to writing in ES6 and compiling down with babel.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
var plakatMenge = ppt2019.getRange(row, 3 + i).getValues();
```

use `getValue()` instead of `getValues()` because the later returns an array of arrays (2D array / multidimensional array) but only a single cell is got by `ppt2019.getRange(row, 3 + i)`.

Then you could use `===` because Google Apps Script returns an empty string as the value of blank (empty) cells.